# Entity Relations in draw.io: change of the text is not allowed

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is there a possibility to edit entries of the elements of the Entity Relation category? E.g. If I want to change name and properties of Entity Extended.The only thing I can do is to add text below the box OR edit the xml manually.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the text value in the style (Edit->Edit Style) of a selected cell to input the text you want, see [this slightly out of date video](http://youtu.be/fpOotAMvn0c). We will add it to the right click menu, but we can't give a date currently.

Note, you can also press cmd/ctrl + E to bring up the style dialog.

Comment: Could you update the answer? it doesn't work anymore.. (Not in Format->Style, nor right click menu)